# Proper way for WHERE clause with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a plugin, and I have one problem.

I'm trying to loop through the database table and to show only the last values from the column.

For example:

```
id | plugin_name                    | plugin_path                   | plugin_time_delay |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Elementor                      | elementor/elementor.php       | 5                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | Health Check & Troubleshooting | health-check/health-check.php | 3                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3  | Elementor                      | elementor/elementor.php       | 7                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I need is to show only the last value for example for `Elementor` value.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$all_plugins = get_plugins();

foreach ( $allPlugins as $key => $allPlugin ) {
    $queryPlugins = $allPlugin['Name'];

    $selectPluginSeconds = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'wdl WHERE plugin_name=".$queryPlugins." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1' );

    foreach ( $selectPluginSeconds as $select_plugin_second ) {
        if ($allPlugin['Name'] == $select_plugin_second->plugin_name) { ?>
            <input type="text" style="width: 200px" value="<?= $select_plugin_second->plugin_time_delay . __( ' seconds.', 'wdl') ?>" disabled>
        <?php }
    }
}
```

In this way I don't get any values, ( [see the image](https://prnt.sc/tkpscu) ) only an empty field. But as soon as I change `$selectPluginSeconds` query on this way ( with static value ) then I get only that static value ( [see the image](https://prnt.sc/tkpssu) ) :

```
$selectPluginSeconds = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'wdl WHERE plugin_name="Elementor" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1' );
```

Comment: You should really [prepare](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) the query before passing it in to `get_results()` instead of concatenate the `$queryPlugins` variable. If some plugin name would contain certain characters (like a single quote), the query will now break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concatenation was a little mixed up, this should work

```
$selectPluginSeconds = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "SELECT * 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wdl 
        WHERE plugin_name='$queryPlugins' 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 1" );
```

Comment: @KUMAR Of course, I will mark, but it needs to pass 10 minutes first. :)